# Using multiple tags to run in karate options

Tags: testing, cucumber, bdd, karate

Let's say I have 4 feature files which is written in karate version 0.9.0.
I am tagging **feature 1** with **@F1**, **feature 2** with **@F2**, **feature 3** with **@F3**, **feature 4** with **@F4**.

On the other hand, I have a runner class which is placed in the root all of those feature files. Now I want to run **@F1**, **@F2** AND **@F3** but not **@F4** tags.

I am using KarateOptions as below:

```
@KarateOptions(tags = {"@F1", "@F2", "@F3", "~@F4"} )
```

Apparently, I am doing something wrong since there are no any output is being appeared in my ***cucumber-html-reports*** file.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1: Here is my whole runner class code:

```
@KarateOptions(tags = {"@F1", "@F2", "@F3", "~@F4"} )
public class TestRunnerAutomation {

@Test
public void testParallel() {
    Results results = Runner.parallel(getClass(), 5);
    generateReport(results.getReportDir());
    assertTrue(results.getErrorMessages(), results.getFailCount() == 0);
}

public static void generateReport(String karateOutputPath) {
    Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[] {"json"}, true);
    List<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList(jsonFiles.size());
    jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "demo");
    ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
    reportBuilder.generateReports();
}
}
```

Comment: @PeterThomas, please do not write un-related answers. If you know something about the question I asked, feel free to answer. Otherwise, please do not post un-related answers.

Comment: @PeterThomas thanks for deleting your un-related comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For running tests using `tags` with multiple conditions, we need to use logic conditions in tags.

**AND**:

To run every feature that has both @F1 and @F2 tags.

`{"@F1", "@F2"}`

**OR**:

To run every feature that has either of the @F1 and @F2 tags (runs both)

`{"@F1,@F2"}`

**Combining OR and AND**:

To run feature that has either of @F1,@F2,@F3 tags but not @F4 tag

`{"@F1,@F2,@F3","~@F4"}`

Comment: Is it working as expected. I am trying to achieve the same with mvn command but it does not seems to work.  I am using the below maven command mvn clean test -Dkarate.options="--tags @F1,~@F2". However it is selecting the tests with tags F2 as well.