# Multiple tags in Karate using and condition

Tags: karate

I have the below variety of tags in my scenarios. These scenarios are distributed in multiple feature files.

1. @smoke
2. @smoke @prod
3. @Regression
4. @Regression @prod

I am executing karate jars via command line as below:

```
java -cp some-jar-with-dependecies:. -Dkarate.config.dir=. -jar  some-jar-with-dependecies.jar *.feature -T 1 -t "@smoke","@prod" -e prod
```

I was expecting scenarios with only `@smoke @prod` i.e only `#2` to get executed.

But I am getting reports with `#1,#2,#4` variations. It seems the tags mentioned in the command line are working as `OR` condition (@smoke or @ prod).

I am trying to call the scenarios with an `AND` condition in the tag.

Please help me on how to execute the scenarios with a tag `AND` condition (@smoke AND @prod).

I found some similar questions in Stack Overflow. But those solutions are not working for me:
[Using multiple tags to run in karate options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863358/using-multiple-tags-to-run-in-karate-options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
-t @smoke -t @prod
```

Which should be "smoke and prod"

Also:

```
-t @smoke -t @prod,@reg
```

Should be "smoke AND (prod OR reg)"

Comment: and if this doesn't work, please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue